# Using generics in generics in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

So let's say I have something like this:

```
type Id<T> = T;
const f = <B>(a: Id<B>, b: B): [Id<B>, B] => [a, b];
```

But I want to extend `f` to be able to use other dependent types

```
type List<T> = T[];
```

How can I achieve something like

```
const f = <A, B>(a: A<B>, b: B): [A<B>, B] => [a, b];
f<Id, number>(1, 2) // evaluates to [1,2]
f<List, number>([1], 2) // evaluates to [[1],2]
```

without typescript complaining that `A` is not generic? Or do the types passed into a generic have to be flat types?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, TypeScript has no direct support for *higher kinded types* (HKTs) of the sort you intend `A` to be.  And you cannot refer to `Id` without immediately specifying its type parameter like `Id<T>` for some `T`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) for a longstanding, open feature request for higher kinded types.  That issue does list out some ways that HKTs can be simulated/emulated in TypeScript, but nothing nice enough that I'd really recommend it.

For example, you can do something like this where you explicitly register every higher-kinded type you care about by [merging it into an interface declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces):

```
type Id<T> = T;
interface HKTRegistry<T> { Id: Id<T> };

type List<T> = T[];
interface HKTRegistry<T> { List: List<T> }
```

And then you could use it like this:

```
const f = <A extends HKT, B>(a: Specify<A, B>, b: B): [Specify<A, B>, B] => [a, b];

const id = f<"Id", number>(1, 2);
const hmm = f<"List", number>([1], 2);
```

where `HKT` and `Specify` are defined like this:

```
type HKT = keyof HKTRegistry<any>
type Specify<H extends HKT, T> = HKTRegistry<T>[H];
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.1.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIGkAqAlCBzYAZzCgE8AeTAPmQG9kBfZAemeQFto8VQwB7DhACwAKDCkADigyZkAXmQBrCKT4w0WXAWJlycEKSqjxU5AGUpCYDAqpkEAB6QQAE0IbMAGmTV5HrUQkFNQA2qgAugDcojEirKzIAJIAIizxxpIoiS6UNAqY0SK80PBI-viBur702QBcSTm+DIWi8WwAMolmsm0Zpu2BuX6YIVGixbCI0poVOsE09APE9UtgQwyxrQkAqmYAggDiAKJprKIIfCDEyOoK5Hv2ThCu7jLeAEJUABRw9RYQVhs9w+VG8ACN6u8AJT1EL-QEUPYgj7heQ0EJwcFjETnS7XYAuPwwcgAImyJO8IAAruwwdBvgBGbwAJihhQuVzAyAAFux2ETSasKchqbT6V8Qgzwiy2aIgA)

But it's clunky and doesn't capture things like [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) type parameters and it's hard to *infer* an HKT this way.  As I said, it's not really in a place I'd recommend for any production code.