# How to infer type parameter definitions of a function type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to extend the following Next.js function type:

```
export type GetStaticProps<
  P extends { [key: string]: any } = { [key: string]: any },
  Q extends ParsedUrlQuery = ParsedUrlQuery,
  D extends PreviewData = PreviewData
> = (
  context: GetStaticPropsContext<Q, D>
) => Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<P>> | GetStaticPropsResult<P>
```

So that 3 properties on its context (`GetStaticPropsContext`) and never `undefined`, like this:

```
type UpdateContext<T> = T extends (context: infer Context extends GetStaticPropsContext) => infer Return
    ? (context: SelectiveRequiredNotUndefined<Context, "locale" | "locales" | "defaultLocale">) => Return
    : never;
```

Now if I do this, I can use the new type where those context properties are never `undefined`:

```
type MyGetStaticProps = UpdateContext<GetStaticProps>;
const getStaticProps: MyGetStaticProps = async (context) => { 
  // do stuff
}
```

The problem is that `MyGetStaticProps` is no longer generic. I know I could always do this instead:

```
type MyProps = {
    someField: string
};

export const getStaticProps: UpdateContext<GetStaticProps<MyProps>> = async (context) => {
  // do stuff
}
```

But I was wondering instead if there would not be a way to infer the type parameter definitions instead to avoid the more verbose syntax?

Just to recap, I am looking for a way to have some sort of `type MyGetStaticProps = UpdateContext<GetStaticProps>;` but that would be supporting `MyGetStaticProps<MyProps>` (infer the type parameters of `GetStaticProps`)

Here is a fully working [Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJ59rm) of the example

Comment: I don't have an answer but your TS playground link just taught me about using `^?` in comments, neat!

Comment: Okay I'm not sure I entirely follow your intent here. Would you be able to simplify your example or provide a more explicit example of what your desired code pattern would look like?

Comment: Yes, basically all I am trying to do is have some sort of `type MyGetStaticProps = UpdateContext<GetStaticProps>;` but that would be supporting `MyGetStaticProps<MyProps>` (infer the type parameters of `GetStaticProps`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately TypeScript cannot currently represent these kinds of types (known as "higher kinded types"), see [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).

You could try and implement them, like this [blog post](https://www.matechs.com/blog/encoding-hkts-in-typescript-once-again) does or [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213#issuecomment-415694540) shows, but it's clunky and not fully representative of what HKTs can do.

It's probably better to use an alternative, or try to rethink your problem or even prevent it in the first place by redesigning some parts of your code.

In short, you can't really take a type, modify it, then spit the type back out, like you can with JS functions:

```
// type GetStaticProps<...> = ...;
function GetStaticProps(...) { ... }

// type UpdateContext<Func ...> = ...;
function UpdateContext(Func) {
    const NewFunc = (...args) => {
        args[0].prop = "something else";

        return Func(...args);
    };

    return NewFunc;
}

// type Updated = UpdateContext<GetStaticProps>;
const Updated = UpdateContext(GetStaticProps);

// type Result = Updated<...>; // but Updated can't be a generic, it's a result of another type.
const Result = Updated({ prop: "will change" });
```

Some HKT comments from jcalz (more in-depth with potential workarounds for you):

- [Higher-order type functions in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60007436/higher-order-type-functions-in-typescript/60008205#60008205)
- [Using generics in generics in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66361623/using-generics-in-generics-in-typescript/66361651#66361651)
- [How can I extend a genric parameter with a generic parameter in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73053170/how-can-i-extend-a-genric-parameter-with-a-generic-parameter-in-typescript/73057143#73057143)

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

It took me a while to wrap my head around what you are trying to achieve here, but I think I finally understand that your goals are:

1. To refine the `GetStaticPropsContext` such that certain properties of the `context` are required and non-nullable.
2. To be able to `infer` the type of the returned props from the function, rather than defining them yourself.

Resolving #2 by itself -- without #1 -- is simple as Next.js exports an `InferGetStaticPropsType<T>` utility type for this.

```js
export type InferGetStaticPropsType<T> = T extends GetStaticProps<infer P, any>
  ? P
  : T extends (
      context?: GetStaticPropsContext<any>
    ) => Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<infer P>>
  ? P
  : never
```

[source](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/cb430cce90ec7120dbc6e0e1020a3f42c4b901a4/packages/next/types/index.d.ts#L128-L134)

The core of your problem is that implementing #1 will make it such that this type no longer works.  This is because a function which accepts broader arguments `extends` a function which accepts a narrower refinement of those arguments, but not the other way around.

An arbitrary illustration of that principle:

```js
// this is `true`
type A = ((arg: number | string) => any) extends ((arg: string) => any) ? true : false;
// this is `false`
type B = ((arg: number) => any) extends ((arg: number | string) => any) ? true : false;
```

If your `getStaticProps` function can only accept a refined `context` type then the `InferGetStaticPropsType<T>` utility type will no longer work because your `getStaticProps` no longer `extends` the basic `GetStaticProps`.

```js
export const getStaticPropsA = async (context: GetStaticPropsContext) => {
    return {
        props: {
            someField: 'yes'
        }
    }
};

// this is `{ someField: string; }`
type PropsA = InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticPropsA>


export const getStaticPropsB = async (context: SelectiveRequiredNotUndefined<GetStaticPropsContext, "locale" | "locales" | "defaultLocale">) => {
    return {
        props: {
            someField: 'yes'
        }
    }
};

// this is `never`
type PropsB = InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticPropsB>
```

#### Solution

Since you want to infer the return type, it doesn't make sense to assign a type like `GetStaticProps` to the entire function.  You'll want to just assign a type to the arguments.  You've already got that part done with your `SelectiveRequiredNotUndefined` utility type.

What's missing is the ability to infer the return type.  For that, we need to modify some of the core Next.js types.

##### Approach 1: Module Augmentation

The `locale`, `locales`, and `defaultLocale` properties are marked as optional because not all apps will use internationalization.  But if your app includes this routing information [in the next.config.js file](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing) then it is safe to assume that these properties will always be present.

You can use [TypeScript module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) to modify the types of the `next` `GetStaticPropsContext` type.

```js
import { PreviewData } from 'next';
import { ParsedUrlQuery } from 'querystring';

declare module 'next' {
    export type GetStaticPropsContext<Q extends ParsedUrlQuery = ParsedUrlQuery> = {
        params?: Q
        preview?: boolean
        previewData?: PreviewData
        locale: string
        locales: string[]
        defaultLocale: string
    }
}
```

This *should* be the easy solution, but sometimes it can be a pain to set up properly.  I thought that we would not have to also override the other types which use this, such as `GetStaticProps` and `InferGetStaticPropsType`, but perhaps we do?

[This playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgcQKYwMowIY2AYwAUoIwBnAGhXS1wONLIGEIA7GVADxioElWAZqihpMOPERLkAKgE8wqKsVQA3YKgDuAEVzYqo2hIbkASqjIBXADbwAvnAEkQcAESsuMFwG4AUKEiwiHCE2FBkqAAmAKpQVgCKFsKycPaOEM4A5ACOiVCyZDBQwKwA5hm%20PhGo%20FahqHAgEBHW9Rnu3BmIPnA9cDDy9Qbi9FLMbBzcADxxcB6orBFkwaHh0bEJSXAAvMthkTHxubIAfNtdvRdwYKHYIGQA-ABccHHdlz1gUKrqGk9wAEYQCBWVDYVhvd6fb6aHQ4P7KNQw3QQy5WCD4bAg54FIqlFEXNEYkFkbGFYolADaAF18b0qgJsNYYAAZdGY1Ck3ElFG2HworgBeD9BTUMR0SSMSa0nqEWbceaLIIUgDWqFknPJVOeYOS9h2SBVao1pS1cB1KQo0peco4CyWIT2a0Omx2DtWBw2eStpx2AAp8OMPM8huLjGN2B5pscAJTbU4MEDAcKTENGUZmSw2SaEY7HPkXAXQIUDOD8IQiGjDCUyAaTaQ%20uDSG0KpapkaS4rl4JUHV5949e7BK3PJtzO1wX1Wi4BiPcP5t6vhiYwSa9q2xrbxpxJ1Apyuh9PmJmTTvCYK5q2DwjDuDuFTCHy8nwAemf2y2H7gAFFOLcwCC4AscJHj5GcCjgEp9zTRhgyg9tyDObAyFkVh8AnGdlw3U4EBRDCPAAOkJdkUVffsAD17lwwNuEItliRIt93goqjZxgfD6UZGxWSJVAGPIyjp2otioURDQ4FIgBBJYwTlP8AIgAQzSuKRhH6PoAAtcDgCIIHMVgMngSD4EaCJgAEdQIj4piBN6L4YAsKBWCCT4YMQexbF8Dy%20ULQIwMMuDFwAJkQ5DUPQoTYLFaDyBYVisPOXo8JooiQSsy5mME1jaJ4sg0ouDLEqE9jUAZJluOIi5SOsljl3wkSfnEt8pLNJyuDk%20oFKUlyFFgZIYE0%20AdL0gyIPQBomjMiy8t6AqejshynJw-tlNcpblt6Mh0lQAAxdQrAiZ4MlkcwMitXkLl5LyfGFeoAFlZDDM4y2EBcwzkBRJhuzqjMMeCyECvMqrgCigA) has some errors, but it *does* get the correct types.

##### Approach 2: Local Types

If augmenting the module is too much of a headache to get working, you can continue what you were already trying which is to create your own modified copies of the Next.js types.  Instead of importing the Next.js versions, you would import from our own local types file.

```
import { GetStaticPropsContext, GetStaticPropsResult } from 'next';
import { ParsedUrlQuery } from 'querystring';

export type MyGetStaticPropsContext<Q extends ParsedUrlQuery = ParsedUrlQuery> =
    GetStaticPropsContext<Q> & Required<Pick<GetStaticPropsContext, 'locale' | 'locales' | 'defaultLocale'>>;

export type MyGetStaticProps<
  P extends { [key: string]: any } = { [key: string]: any },
  Q extends ParsedUrlQuery = ParsedUrlQuery
> = (context: MyGetStaticPropsContext<Q>) => Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<P>>

export type MyInferGetStaticPropsType<T> = T extends MyGetStaticProps<infer P, any>
  ? P
  : T extends (
      context?: MyGetStaticPropsContext<any>
    ) => Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<infer P>>
  ? P
  : never

// ==== Example use:

export const getStaticProps = async (context: MyGetStaticPropsContext) => {
    context.locale
    //       ^? (property) locale: string
    context.locales
    //       ^? (property) locales: string[]
    context.defaultLocale
    //       ^? (property) defaultLocale: string
    context.preview // As an example of a property that doesn't get modified
    //       ^? (property) preview?: boolean | undefined
    return {
        props: {
            someField: 'yes'
        }
    }
};

type MyProps = MyInferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>
//   ^? type MyProps = { someField: string; }
```

[Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgcQKYwMowIY2AYwAUoIwBnAYQgDsZUAPGAGhXS1wONLICVUyArgBt4AXzgAzEiDgAiagxiyA3AChQkWIjiFsUMqgAmAVShCAigNRQAnnHFSIMgOQBHK7bIwowagHNnNVUGTXgYGzBUOABZGzRMHDwiEnIqWkUAHnM4RVRqQzIdPQMTM0trOwBeIv0jUwsPGwA%20OErVOA7WBI5k7jS6RiyWgDI4PndgKCMMwgIAawz49iSuVJoB5jhnIQh8bCFUZzgAHy2dvYOyI9PnQ1QJbGEYABld-cOmpqCQ6DCIqNiS0SnBSZAy7R0OUYeQK2gA2nNUDYAFxwLw%20fwAXVR2GodnE1SQCKRqPRvj82LguPxTAh2Vy%20UKulqpQaFVaNRK9XKtlULWqAAp8OtFKjAWxgb01ulBuYmgBKVotLggYAGRYSnqrXj8J4zT6qYL0UJwcKRGI2ACS1Ak1iBWtBABV-hlHfy4I6oXRGRb7StQRlfLaoDoWNSmhCAPw6CGoz0M2ECiGdODCmUwSNiuKa-19EWDcPJuCKyrK6Rq1Aa7q58h8QQiQM26w6A0daOEWNwBQAN2shoA9P3WpUR3AAKL0bDgA5wAQGZGGn5aNNeOB%20HMg7gc7BkGzUfBwIX5mBZv2b6UbEstBBFtMbAB053eRcHKc6AD1I7fj4%203pcX0Ob5wJ%2037pvedwPE8rwXKgAFAcBX4pneij3mAUzdsAqAAO5wK%20ACChS4lCU5gDOEASFScBoaQ1jhKaAAWuBwIYED8NQzjwOu8AgBAhjABImGGHBQEgSmUwwAIUDUIgRYptR5Coje8FvmQTioAAYphQiGKizg2PwziyZ0ohFiZohBGaAI2NqHKxNawZnlKZDOpEGSWeRa4bk5Eavh0n5AA)

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. You actually provided us with the same solutions that we already tried but what I was looking for was to know if there is a way to create a new custom `GetStaticProps` while inferrering the original's function generic signature (without having to copy paste this `<
  P extends { [key: string]: any } = { [key: string]: any },
  Q extends ParsedUrlQuery = ParsedUrlQuery,
  D extends PreviewData = PreviewData
>`) I think there isn't a way in TypeScript but I just wanted to confirm (this is the answer I am looking for!)

Comment: @NicolasBouvrette I think that it's theoretically possible with the module augmentation approach, but I just could not get it working and basically gave up.